# Use Ubuntu $Home in Java

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

Is there any way to use the `$Home` variable of Ubuntu (or Linux in common) in Java? I'm using Eclipse and if I use `$Home` as path, it throws an error.
But if I use `/home/USERNAME` everything works fine. 
In order to write a portable program I need a way to define the home-path in a general way.
So I would be glad about a solution for this problem. 
Cheers!

Comment: You could also do some reading about *environment variables* and how to access those in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expansion of things like `$home` is a feature of the shell. It has no meaning in Java. If you want to know the user directory, get the system property `"user.home"`, eg

```
System.getProperty("user.home");
```

See also [System Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) in the Java Tutorial.

Comment: Ok thank you! That’s exactly what I needed! Yeah, I know... but I didn’t know how to describe my problem differently 

Comment: Does this also work on Windows and Mac? According to the manual it should right?

Comment: @lpsweder Yes, it should work on MacOS and Windows as well.